# how to store OLD object in one column in json fromat inside trigger

Tags: mysql, database, database-trigger, mysql-5.6

For example:

```
Drop trigger if EXISTS trig_delete_test_outlet;
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER trig_delete_test_outlet AFTER DELETE ON outlets

 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    Insert into `log`.`tempdata`( data, table ) values(OLD, 'outlets');
 END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Please **suggest** some way, so that dynamically I can create a trigger for any table and can store data in one table.

Comment: Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html.

Comment: i have to save complete OLD object in one column ...is there any way?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do this with any sql table - why would OLD be any different?